# Converting Dataframe to Numpy Array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have 3 columns in my df

[image]

How can i convert this to a matrix? I tried

```
numpy_matrix=df.as_matrix()
```

but this doenst give a matrix

Comment: use `df.values` ?

Comment: Don't use a matrix, they have a special meaning with numpy and their usage is not advised.

Comment: I need to perform matrix algebra after this step

Answer (score 1):

In pandas 0.24.0+, it is recommended that you use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy). The function `as_matrix` was deprecated in pandas 0.23.0.

```
df.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a pandas dataframe (df) to a numpy ndarray, use this code:

```
df = df.values
```

df now becomes the numpy ndarray: